# xcode - failed to get reply to handshake packet

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, handshake

When I make a build, the build is installed in the device but XCode is giving this error:

"failed to get reply to handshake packet"

and it won't launch the game, so I'm not able to see the console for debugging. The game runs fine if I manually start it in the device. I need the see the console for debugging.

My XCode version is 5.1
iOS version in the device is 7.1 (iPod Touch 5th gen)
Unity is 4.3.3

I really appreciate any solution from you guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is from Xcode or your server or compiler?

Answer (score 9):

This might be a bit late for the op, but I found that my problem was caused by having my app running manually on the device. It seems that if you launch the app on the device then xcode can't connect to the process and the handshake error is reported.

Comment: In my case it also helped. When I removed the app from recent (double 'Home' -> swipe up) Xcode was finaly able to proceed

Answer (score 7):

I know it's a late answer, but in my case a simple Clean command solved the problem.

Comment: I can't see how this is not an answer to the question. It seems to me like a perfectly acceptable answer. Please make sure you really do understand an answer before flagging it as not-an-answer. If you don't know the Xcode IDE (which your profile seems to suggest), then please assume you do not understand the answer.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> solved my issue.

This combination actually cleans the build folder. This way the next build will be fresh and will remove any issues in the previous build(s).

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate a little what this key combination does and why exactly it solves the problem? Perhaps add a link to the appropriate documentation?

Comment: I think it cleans the output/build folder.  This fixed the issue for me as well. Always nice to have a *shortcut* instead of needing to do serial clicking on random icons on the gui

Answer (score 3):

Restart of the device solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're not running using a release configuration.

Go to Product Menu > Scheme > Edit Scheme and make sure that the Run item is using the Debug build configuration.

Comment: I just checked in the Scheme and it is using Debug configuration. It was working well before updating the iOS (7.0) version and XCode.

Comment: It's not just lack of symbols. Release builds set the entitlement get-task-allow to false so the debugger can't connect. The error message is not exactly the same, but it's not crazy either.

Comment: I just did the "Reset All Settings" thing in the settings of the device and it's working now. It seems like the problem was with the device. Thanks to everyone for the answers.

Comment: @trojanfoe: This is a perfectly acceptable answer, not a comment.

Comment: @KPM Agreed; comment deleted.